# Replace spaces with ~ in (ba)sh with no external command

Tags: bash, sh

I have a string that can contain multiple spaces (and tabs) and also terminate with spaces (but it will never start with spaces).

Something like: `"topo pippo    pluto   "`

I need to remove the spaces at the end and replace any remaining sequence of spaces with `~`. In the previous example, I'd get `"topo~pippo~pluto"`.

I'm currently doing it with:

```
mystring=$(echo "$mystring" | sed -e 's/\s\s*/~/g' -e 's/~~*$//' )
```

but I really would love to find a faster way (possibly not having to invoke external commands). I'd like to be shell-independent but a bash-only solution is fine too (I'll have to use bash for other reasons).

I've tried with the various bash `${}` variants but I couldn't find any solution.

Any suggestion on where to look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Bash:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ str='topo pippo    pluto   '
$ str=${str%%+([[:blank:]])}
$ echo "<$str>"
<topo pippo    pluto>
$ str=${str//+([[:blank:]])/'~'}
$ echo "<$str>"
<topo~pippo~pluto>
```

The `extglob` option is required to enable the `+(pattern)` pattern. `${str%%+([[:blank:]])}` removes all blanks from the end of the string; `${str//+([[:blank:]])/'~'}` replaces all runs of blanks with a `~`.

Comment: Use `+([[:space:]])` to replace tabs _and_ spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed the existence of extglob! As first transformation I had to add `str=${str// / }` (there is a tab character right after the two slashes) to deal with tabs. Then it worked perfectly!

Comment: @hmm Or `[[:blank:]]` – `[[:space:]]` includes a few more things in addition to blanks and spaces.

Answer (score 3):

A POSIX shell solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

mystring="topo pippo    pluto   "

# Disable pathname expansion so the parameters expansion
# will not capture pathes if mystring contains patterns
set -f

# Feed mystring as arguments list
# where each space separated element (word) is an argument
set -- $mystring

# Restore pathname expansion
set +f

# Set ~ as the field separator
IFS='~'

# Expand the parameters into mystring with ~ as separator
mystring="$*"

# Restore the default field separator
unset IFS

echo "$mystring" # Print topo~pippo~pluto
```

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in the documentation of `bash` (run `man bash` on your terminal) under the section "Parameter Expansion":

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> **Pattern substitution**.  The `pattern` is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion. `Parameter` is expanded and the longest match of `pattern` against its value is replaced with `string`.
>   If `pattern` begins with `/`, all matches of `pattern` are replaced with `string`.  Normally only the first match is replaced.
>   If `pattern` begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of `parameter`.
>   If `pattern` begins with `%`, it must match at the end of the expanded value of `parameter`.
>   If `string` is null, matches of `pattern` are deleted and the `/` following pattern may be omitted.
>   If parameter is `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
>   If `parameter` is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

You cannot do both replacements in a single command, you have to use it twice (once to replace the sequences of spaces with `~` and once to remove the last `~`:

```
X="topo pippo    pluto   "

# Enable the extended pattern matching
shopt -s extglob

# Replace the sequences of spaces with ~
Y="${X//+( )/\~}"
echo "[$Y]"          # prints: [topo~pippo~pluto~]

# Replace the trailing ~
Z="${Y%\~}"
echo "[$Z]"          # prints: [topo~pippo~pluto]
```

Remarks:

- The square brackets in the `echo` statements above do not have any special meaning. I used them to clearly show the boundaries of the strings.
- `~` is a special symbol in Bash and in other shells. It means the home directory of the user and it is replaced with its actual value. It needs to be escaped to represent itself.
- `+( )` is an extended pattern (it means "one or more of the patterns present between parenthesis"); it works only when the `extglob` shell option is enabled (using `shopt`); apparently it is enabled by default but in scripts you cannot rely on default values; you better set it to be sure it works;
- `${Y%\~}` is another parameter expansion (it is also explained in the documentation); it removes from `$Y` the last matching suffix (`~`); as explained above `~` needs to be escaped (`\~`) to be interpreted as itself and not as the home directory.